# Nonanticipativity constraint (filtration/measure theory)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am trying to show that stochastic process must attend the nonanticipativity constraint using filtration in measure theory. Adaptability of a stochastic process tell us that:

$$\sigma(X_t)\subset \mathcal{F}_t,$$

where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the natural filtration of the random variable $X_t$. So this is telling me that all the information in period $t$ is contained in the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ which caries all the information up to period $t$. Hence, we do not have information regarding periods $t+1$ at period $t$. My question is, does it suffice to put it this way to show the nonanticipativity constraint? Or we need a more elaborate proof for it? Perhaps using the information that a if a random variable is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable if and only if it is constant?

Thanks!

Comment: From the context I believe you are assuming $\{X_t\}$ to be a discrete-time process; is this correct?

Comment: yes, precisely!